# Who is higher in ranking and authority in "Resident Evil", Chief Irons, or Albert Wesker?

Tags: resident-evil-2-2019, resident-evil-2002, resident-evil-series, resident-evil-1996, resident-evil-2-1998

In the remakes of *Resident Evil* and the originals as well, S.T.A.R.S. is also part of the Raccoon City police department, even having their own office. However, seeing how they are their own specialized unit, it has left me with the question: Who has more power and a higher ranking: Albert Wesker or the police chief, Brian Irons?

While I know that Albert Wesker obviously has more power due to working as a more direct employee of Umbrella Corp., from his pretend job, who would technically have more power from that perspective?

Comment: As far as I remember, I've never witnessed about this in game and books. We need speculation to answer this, so... opinion-based off topic?

Answer (score 1):

Brian Irons. The police chief runs the police department. And if Wesker had more authority in the police department wouldn't one of the other members of stars, who were all working to expose umbrella, take up his title and be able work without chief Irons interfering? In what universe does a specialized unit have more authority than the guy who set it up?